# Table of Contents Title and First Section on same line

Tags: table-of-contents, titles

Absolute beginner, so apoligises in advance if this is a simple fix.

I'm trying to generate the title of contents above the first section heading, currently, they are overlapping like in the image below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{warwick}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\addto\captionsbritish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table Of Contents}%
    }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\section{Introduction} \label{Introduction}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `warwick` package which I (and maybe many others) do not have. When running your MWE and ignoring the `File warwick.sty not found` the ToC was typeset as normal with no overlappings.

Perhaps you should take up your problem with the author/maintainer of the `warwick` package.

--- GOM